# Place buttons one below the other

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have 2 buttons but both of them are on the same line, so one of them is not clickable and not even readable.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#343535"
    tools:context=".fragments.GeneralFragment">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/hello"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/observed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:drawableBottom=""
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/observed" />

</FrameLayout>
```

How can I display them one below the other?

Comment: try using linear layout

Comment: @Madhur just what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is just using `LinearLayout`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#343535"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".fragments.GeneralFragment">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/observed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:drawableBottom=""
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/observed" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are currently using FrameLayout, which should only be used when you have only one view under the FrameLayout.

To fulfill your requirements, you should use **LinearLayout** with **vertical orientation**.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`

```
           <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#343535"
                tools:context=".fragments.GeneralFragment">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/hello"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/hello"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/observed"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/hello"   //Added Layout below
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:drawableBottom=""
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/observed" />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Using LinearLayout you can set android:orientation="vertical" to get element adjusted to below automatically

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable layout is the constraint layout you can work with just like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```